# PWM signal drop on low Duty Cycle

Tags: transistors, pwm, mppt

Glad to found an "electrical engineer"-version of stackoverflow, I greet you all.

I am working on a MPPT projects, using 5V solar panel, and MCU ATTiny24 (for its ability working on a low voltage).

The solar panel output is used for MCU voltage source and load.
The problem is, PWM signal generated is not square if its on low duty cycle (see pics)

I also attach my schematics (sorry for the hand drawing, but I cant access the schematics right now)
Now I am using PNP transistor C9012 for switching.
My first guess is error caused by the transistor, anyone knows a P channel FET to switch low voltage? or maybe a P-channel substitution equal to MPF102?

When the duty cycle is higher than 60%, the signal is square.
I use load ranging from 1 ohm to 50k ohm.
Thanks in advance :)
Ps: sorry i can only post 2 links because of lack of reputation
[image: Schematic]

**EDITED**--------------------------------------------------------
I have try to modify the circuit as the suggestion, but still got the same result (and I'm sure the oscilloscope works).
*sorry have to remove the former circuit, cant upload more than 2

[image]

Comment: Post whatever you need

Comment: For pmos look for bss84. Ah, load may matter. In steady state inductor current is at average like load current.

Comment: Hi Gregory, thanks for joining. The load is just a resistor. no feedback from load (i think). It drops mostly when the resistance is too small, making the current for load is too big and decreasing current for avr. I'm terribly sorry if I am wrong, please let me try to keep up

Comment: Then it's inductance of pv or wires. Try adding some wires in parallel, see it there will be any effect. In any case it should not affect efficiency, i guess.

Comment: Thanks Gregory, can you specify where I should add wires in parallel?

Comment: The two wires coming to VCC and GND. By the way, what is your input capacitance? I can only see 100nF on the scheme. Maybe you have to make it 100uF.

Comment: I will make the input capacitance into 100uF and try using bss84 instead of PNP transistor. Sorry but I am a little confused in "add two wires coming to VCC and GND", I am sure you does not mean to short the circuit right? My English is not so good and so does my electronics comprehensive

Comment: No, no. Wait with the wires. While writing about wires, i did not check the input capacitor. Probably that's the reason. If not- you will have first to answer: what wires connect your solar panel to this circuit.

Comment: And one more thing. BSS84 is very nice, but i am not sure what current do you need. So check the load current please.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, about the wires, I use 45 mm cables with alligator clips. The load current is up to 120mA

Comment: Pretty short. Unless you use very thin wires, the capacitor should solve the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48157/discussion-between-dpw-and-gregory-kornblum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now we know it's input capacitor. By the way, the MOSFET on your drawing is reversed. You should connect the source to VCC. It will conduct when the gate is pulled to zero.

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't notice about the MOSFET drawing. Thanks!

Comment: I still have a question. Why not using integrated chip?

Comment: which part do you mean?

Comment: At least the switch should be inside. Depending on your choice the diode may be inside either.

Comment: Well since the purpose of this is educational, I try to build the circuit "as raw as it can"

Comment: Good job then. Now try improving the efficiency and size. Find a way to use NMOS instead PMOS.

Comment: Yep, I am gonna try to use NMOS, and also try the former circuit (using PNP)

Answer (score 1):

To answers you question completely, some missing information is needed.  It depends if the load is connected when this waveform is generated and what value is.  Is it resistive.  The value of the base resistor is also needed to understand what is going on.  The first thing you need to verify is the transistor turn on isn't causing the the solar cell voltage to drop.  If this is the case, no transistor choice is going to make a difference.  If the solar sell is not dropping when the transistor is turned on, try more base current.  Do this by reducing the size of the base resistor.  If you can't reduce the size of the base resistor, try adding a little capacitance across it.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the reply. The load is resistive, it occurs mostly when the load is lower than 10 ohm. About the transistor, I'm pretty sure its causing the voltage from solar cell dropping, because the transistor is used to drive a buck converter, which is also using voltage from solar cell. Don't you think adding capacitor will make it worse? because the capacitive traits will make the signal "less square"?

Comment: If the voltage at the solar sell is dropping similar what you see in your scope photo, no different device will fix this.  The capacitor on the base resistor will also not help.  You could try more capacitance across the solar cell.  Under heavy load, more current will be taken out of the solar cell when the transistor takes over form the diode.  This current will cause a drop across the solar cell source resistance causing the drop.  The drop will appear at both ends of the switch.  More capacitance will help.  Otherwise you need a bigger badder solar cell.